# How to take measures of 4 rows sequentially for multiples variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I`m struggling on how can I take the measure of 4 rows sequentially for multiples variables in my dataframe sorting by the date. Here is a toy example

```
test = data.frame(my_groups = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C",  "A", "A","A","A","A","A" , "C"),
                  measure1 = c(10:24),
                  measure2 = c(1:15),
                  time= c("20-09-2020", "25-09-2020", "19-09-2020", "20-05-2020", "20-06-2021", 
                          "11-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "15-01-2021", "15-01-2021",
                          "20-03-2021", "20-10-2021", "29-06-2021", "20-07-2021", "13-06-2021"))
#    my_groups measure1 measure2       time
# 1          A       18        9 15-01-2021
# 2          A       19       10 15-01-2021
# 3          A       12        3 19-09-2020
# 4          A       20       11 20-03-2021
# 5          A       23       14 20-07-2021
# 6          A       10        1 20-09-2020
# 7          A       21       12 20-10-2021
# 8          A       11        2 25-09-2020
# 9          A       22       13 29-06-2021
# 10         B       13        4 20-05-2020
# 11         B       14        5 20-06-2021
# 12         C       15        6 11-01-2021
# 13         C       16        7 13-01-2021
# 14         C       17        8 13-01-2021
# 15         C       24       15 13-06-2021
```

As result I'd like something like:

```
#    my_groups measure1    measure2    time
# 1          A       17.25     8.25      20-03-2021  #mean for the first 4 elements of A and maximun date
# 2          A       16.25     7.25      25-09-2020  #mean for the others 4 elements of A and maximun date
# 3          C       18        9         13-06-2021  #mean for the first 4 elements of B and maximun date
```

To get this result I thought of using something like this:

```
test %>% 
  arrange( my_groups,time) %>% 
  group_by(my_groups) %>% 
  summarise(measure1 = mean(measure1),
            measure2 = mean(measure2), 
            time = max(time))
```

But I'm having problem to find a solution to take these measures for 4 values consecutively.

Any hint on how can I do that?

Comment: You can use `rollapply` for the means.

Comment: and for the date?

Comment: I'm not sure... maybe just the maximum, maybe someone have a better idea

Comment: in my real case a have a lot of variables that I need to take this mean, not just the `measure1` and `measure2`, but the logic will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add another grouping variable `g4` using integer division to ensure that we get groups of 4, and if desired, drop groups with fewer members. Then just run your `summarize`.

```r
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  arrange(my_groups, time) %>% 
  group_by(my_groups) %>% 
  mutate(g4 = (row_number() - 1) %/% 4) %>%
  group_by(my_groups, g4) %>%
  filter(n() == 4) %>%
  summarise(measure1 = mean(measure1),
            measure2 = mean(measure2), 
            time = max(time),
            .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   my_groups    g4 measure1 measure2 time      
#>   <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1 A             0     17.2     8.25 20-03-2021
#> 2 A             1     16.2     7.25 25-09-2020
#> 3 C             0     18       9    13-06-2021
```

Comment: nice idea! I'll try this out in my real case. I can't use elements when I don't have the 'full' group of 4

Comment: In thins case, what is the difference of using or not the `.groups = "drop"`?

Comment: @DR15 It just explicitly drops the group, otherwise you get a little warning that the data is regrouped by `my_groups` (the default is `.groups = "drop_last"`).

Comment: Works for me! Nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

Function "f" creates a sliding window (if you do windowing function much, I really recommend the slider package).  Function "g" simply applies the function to all numeric windows.  The final group_modify step applies the functions to the data and filters the good data.

```
library(slider)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

test = data.frame(my_groups = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C",  "A", "A","A","A","A","A" , "C"),
                  measure1 = c(10:24),
                  measure2 = c(1:15),
                  time= dmy(c("20-09-2020", "25-09-2020", "19-09-2020", "20-05-2020", "20-06-2021", 
                          "11-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "15-01-2021", "15-01-2021",
                          "20-03-2021", "20-10-2021", "29-06-2021", "20-07-2021", "13-06-2021"))) %>% 
       arrange(my_groups, time)  %>%
       group_by(my_groups)

f <- function(x) {t <- slide_mean(x, before=3, complete=T, step = 4)}
g <- function(y) {s <- y %>% map_if(is.numeric,  ~ f(.x)) %>% bind_cols()}
x <- test %>% group_modify(~ g(.x)) %>% filter(!(is.na(measure1) | is.na(measure2)))

  my_groups measure1 measure2 time      
  <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl> <date>    
1 A             12.8     3.75 2021-01-15
2 A             21      12    2021-07-20
3 C             18       9    2021-06-13
```

The differences between my and the answers above are because I translated the dates from character, so they sorted differently than as text.